# Scrollback in Vim 8 Terminal

Tags: terminal, scrolling

Been really loving the asynchronous terminal in Vim 8. Sometimes I have a large amount of output in the terminal, and when I enter normal mode in the terminal and use `gg` to go to the top, I see that it is cut off. How can I increase the scrollback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the option `termwinscroll` as documented at `:help terminal-normal` and `:help termwinscroll`.

```
'termwinscroll' 'twsl'  number  (default 10000)
        local to buffer
        {not in Vi}
        {not available when compiled without the
        |+terminal| feature}
Number of scrollback lines to keep.  When going over this limit the
first 10% of the scrollback lines are deleted.  This is just to reduce
the memory usage.  See |Terminal-Normal|.
```

Thus, you may increase the limit using for example,

```
set termwinscroll=40000
```